# graph search api locale filter not working in any combination?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, locale

I have tried several times to resolve this but its not clear whats the latest from FB regarding as a reported bug...or not? Either way when using the graph search api and specifying a locale filter for the results it does not work.

For example, locale in English:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&locale=en_US

It will return posts in a myriad of languages. I have tested with other languages, no dice. I have also tried the locale and content filters and headers still no improvement in result and have tried various combinations of case, still not working, have tried with and without access_tokens still no change in result. There are reported bugs on FB site with no resolution and I am being redirected here hence the post.

Am following the FB docs here....
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/locale/

Any help much appreciated, Thx, Digby.

Comment: Any confirmation either way would be a huge benefit. I have tried several other locales and none of them appear to work, here we are with French and its the same posts. How can I report this as a bug to facebook?

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&locale=fr_FR

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294623187324442 - but it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Not working for me either. Must be a bug.

This might be of help to some people:

http://blog.nuit.dk/facebook-graph-api-search-workaroun/